# Get List of Modified Objects within Entity Framework 7

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dbcontext, entity-framework-core

I am stumped - upgrading to Entity Framework 7 and I typically override the SaveChanges inside the `DbContext` to be able to get a list of all the Modified Objects before it changes. Ultimately I have a script that fires that tracks the previous version in a database. In Entity Framework 6 I would get the model changes like so:

```
var oc = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;
var modifiedItems = oc.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Modified | EntityState.Deleted);

List<ObjectStateEntry> ModifiedObjlist = modifiedItems.ToList();
```

However now that `ObjectContext` is removed within Entity Framework 7, I am stuck, how would I inside Entity Framework 7 get a list of the modified objects?

Comment: use `context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x=> x.State == ... )`

Comment: @dotctor add as an answer so I can accept that answer

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [DbContext.ChangeTracker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.changetracker(v=vs.113).aspx)

```
var modifiedEntries = context.ChangeTracker
       .Entries()
       .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Modified)
       .Select(x =>x.Entity)
       .ToList();
```

Comment: How would I get the Modified Properties from ChangeTracker

Comment: @kevinc context.Entry(someObject).Properties.Where(m => m.IsModified);

Comment: @ScottE I don't see any Properties property available for DbEntityEntry class [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbentityentry?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)

Answer (score 1):

@dotctor 's code may not work in some cases.

There are certain instances where the change tracker may not have the *latest* information with regards to the entities being managed by the context, so an entity could be modified/added/deleted without the change tracker being aware. To avoid this case, I would wrap the @dotctor 's code in the following conditional:

```
if(context.ChangeTracker.HasChanges())
{
  ...
}
```

**Microsoft Summary of ChangeTracker.HasChanges()**:

Checks if any new, deleted, or changed entities are being tracked such that these changes will be sent to the database if DbContext.SaveChanges or DbContext.SaveChangesAsync is called. Note that this method calls ChangeTracker.DetectChanges unless ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled has been set to false.